# How to convert LinkedList<String> to LinkedList<int> using Linq ?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to convert `LinkedList<String>` to `LinkedList<int>` using Linq ?
What is the best way to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: Big assumption: you want `Int32.Parse`? Or perhaps `s.Length.ToString()`? Or perhaps `s.GetHashCode()`? Additional information is necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`LinkedList<T>` contains a constructor that receives an `IEnumerable<T>` and initializes based on it. So all you have to do is use LINQ's `Select` operator to convert all strings to int:

```
LinkedList<string> stringList = ...;
IEnumerable<int> ints = stringList.Select(str => int.Parse(str));
LinkedList<int> intList = new LinkedList<int>(ints);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
LinkedList<string> stringLinkedList = new LinkedList<string>(new[] { "1", "2", "3" });
LinkedList<int> intLinkedList = new LinkedList<int>(stringLinkedList.Select(i => Int32.Parse(i)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you wanted a linq solution how about:

```
 List<int> integ = st.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToList();
```

where st is a List

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
LinkedList<string> stringTest = new LinkedList<string>();
LinkedList<int> intTest = new LinkedList<int>(stringTest.Cast<int>());
```

Sorry, disregard - I didn't notice he was asking specifically for a Linq solution.